# Segmentation Fault when utilizing struct array dereference

Tags: c++, linux, fault

I'm working on a school assignment. It is an assignment in which every 2 weeks, we have to either expand or change the layout of it. This week, we are forced to use pointers. I'm having a hard time understanding memory and how to allocate it properly without having segmentation faults.

I've created a struct array which is initialized to a char pointer. Every time i loop, after the 1st loop i get "segmentation faults". I simply don't understand why?

I could include the whole code but according to gdb my issue is pertaining to 1 specific line.

```
const int arraySize = 100;
int counter = 0;

struct contacts{
  char * name;
  char * date;
  char * note;
};

contacts * contactList[arraySize] = 
contactList = new contacts;

for(int i = 0; i <= counter; i++){
  contactList[i]->name = new char[20];  //Segmentation Fault here
  std::cout <<  contactList[i]->name << std::endl; 
  //first 1 outputs = fine
  //2nd output = segmentation error
  counter++;
}
```

The code is simplified and minimilized for easy reading. If anyone wants it i can insert the whole code. Just be wary that is relatively big. I have set breakpoint through my code to narrow it down. It has come down to that specific statement. Everything else i perfectly fine, especially since it all compiles perfectly fine.

Any hints or assistance with it can be great.

Also I'm not allowed to use any vectors, strings, etc., only cstrings.
User mentioned that i only create 1 contact.

```
contacts * contactList[arraySize];
contactList = new contacts;
//Instead it should be like this:
contacts * contactList[arraySize];
contactList = new contacts[arraySize];
```

Update:
I've tried using what everyone recommended.

```
contacts* contactList[arraySize];
contactList = new contacts[arraySize];
```

But i get this error:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of‘ContactClass::contacts*’ to ‘ContactClass::contacts* [100]’
```

Comment: `new contacts;` you created only one `contacts` object. should be  `new contacts[arraySize];`

Comment: Not only that, but `contacts * contactList[arraySize] = new contacts;` should not even compile.

Comment: You want `contacts * contactList= new contacts[arraySize];` or even better `std::vector<contacts> contactList(arraySize);`

Comment: Don't use pointers and `new` or `new[]` for collections or strings. Use [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

Comment: If you continue to use pointers for strings, remember that `new[]` in itself doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, its contents will be *indeterminate*. Therefore your output of `name` would lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude school assignment :/ _"This week, we are forced to use pointers."_

Comment: If instead of `contacts * contactList[arraySize] = new contacts;` you write `std::vector<contacts> contactList;` you reduce the amount of possible mistakes in that single line from almost infinite to almost zero. You need really good reasons not to use this opportunity

Comment: Look again at the text book

Comment: ...well school assignment is a reason, though not really a good one :/

Comment: @tobi303: unfortunately, not all schools have figured that out.

Comment: 1. code is not complete. 2. Probably You have plenty of warnings, maybe errors from compiler

Comment: `contacts * contactList[arraySize]; contactList[counter] = new contacts;` instantiates 1 contact in the array of pointers at index `counter`, `contacts * contactList = new contacts[arraySize];` instantiates a dynamic list of `contacts` objects. `contacts * contactList[arraySize];
contactList[counter] = new contacts[arraySize];` is invalid code.

Comment: About your update: you misinterpreted what was recommended, see my previous comment and the answer.

Comment: @stefaanv right but i set up a 'contacts * contactList[ArraySize]' within the header file. Then i initialized it in the constructor as 'contactList = new contacts[arraySize]". I still received the error i got above. I can't have it be stated in a single statement per my professors instructions.

Comment: Your header should have `contacts * contactList;`.  This is the pointer to the dynamic array that will be instantiated with `contactList = new contacts[arraySize];`. After this you will have an array of arraySize contacts.

Comment: @stefaanv Thank You, it works now the way i want it to!

Comment: The important part is, I hope you now have a better grasp on how pointers and allocation work.  2 points though: 1. when allocating, never forget to deallocate, 2. when possible avoid manually allocating, it's error-prone and there are better ways as already mentioned in previous comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is in this line:

```
contacts * contactList[arraySize] = new contacts;
```

it should be

```
contacts* contactList = new contacts[arraySize];
```

next problem is here

```
for(int i = 0; i <= counter; i++){
```

should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
    contactList[i].name = new char[20];
}
```

Comment: In this case, it should also be `contactList[i].name`

Comment: @stefaanv THX, fixed.

Comment: Shouldn't    'contactList[i].name'  be changed to 'contactList[i]->name' ?